# CMake adding a library

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

I am currently simply trying to add a library to one of the [example](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera.html) for VTK.
So let's imagine we have this scenario in which I want to redefine the behavior or the trackball. What I did in that is to create my own trackball (based on the model provided by `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera`). So I created two files: InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cpp and InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h

When I CMake, everything is just fine. However when I open the solution with Visual Studio 2013 and try to build the all_build target I get an error stating:

> InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h no such file or directory.

I know of course what it means, however I cannot understand why I get this error. It may be that my CMakeLists.txt is kind of broken (it is the only thing I can think of), so here it is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(TrackballCamera)

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

add_executable(TrackballCamera MACOSX_BUNDLE TrackballCamera)
add_library(InteractorStyleTrackballCamera InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cpp InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h)

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(TrackballCamera ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(TrackballCamera vtkHybrid vtkWidgets InteractorStyleTrackballCamera)
endif()
```

When I look at my solution explorer in VS13 I can clearly see 4 solutions, `ALL_BUILD`, `InteractorStyleTrackballCamera` (with the header and cpp) `TrackballCamera` and `ZERO_CHECK`. So that's what is puzzling me. Isn't it right that if the header is included in my solution explorer it should be found when I try to build ?

Oh and if you wonder what's inside my `InteractorStyleTrackballCamera` (not sure this is really relevant for that problem) I simply copied/pasted the content of `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera` and replaced all the `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera` by `InteractorStyleTrackballCamera`

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: The error does not come from the file `InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cpp` but from the file `TrackballCamera.cxx` when I try to include my header. 
Basically the line is:

`#include <InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.h>`

Comment: Show the `#include` directive in `InteractorStyleTrackballCamera.cpp`, please. I assume it's from that file that the compilation error is reported. If not, please specify more.

Comment: See edit above. The error does not come from the cpp file but from the TrackballCamera.cxx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#include <...>` should only be used for including library headers. If you want to include a header file from your source directory, use `#include "..."`.

With most compilers, the difference is that `#include "..."` also searches the source file's directory for the file to include, while `#include <...>` only searches include directories specified on the compiler's command-line (plus possibly some default ones).

---

Unrelated to the original question, but it seems to me you should link `InteractorStyleTrackballCamera` even when `VTK_LIBRARIES` is defined:

```
if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(TrackballCamera InteractorStyleTrackballCamera ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(TrackballCamera vtkHybrid vtkWidgets InteractorStyleTrackballCamera)
endif()
```

Comment: Ok this definitely helps, it was a stupid error from me, sorry about that. However it seems that the linking is not correct now. I have a LNK2019: `"__declspec(dllimport) public: static class InteractorStyleTrackballCamera * __cdecl InteractorStyleTrackballCamera::New(void)" (__imp_?New@InteractorStyleTrackballCamera@@SAPAV1@XZ) referenced in the function "public: static class vtkSmartPointer<class InteractorStyleTrackballCamera> __cdecl vtkSmartPointer<class InteractorStyleTrackballCamera>::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VInteractorStyleTrackballCamera@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)`

Comment: @LBesancon Expanded the answer, although it's largely a separate issue.

Comment: If it's a separate issue then I should create a new post I guess. The answer you provided about that did not help so I might as well create a separate post.

Comment: First doing some research about that kind of issue and I'll create a new post if I can't find the answer

Answer (score 3):

I see the question has been answered. In addition, have a read of the documentation of

`target_include_directories`

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_include_directories.html#command:target_include_directories

In CMAKE, you can imbue a target with properties that it carries forward into targets that depend on it. One such properties is the "include directories". This property is different in the following 3 scenarios:

1. Your target is itself being built
2. Your target is in the same project as the dependency
3. Your target has been installed and is being picked up with find_package

`target_include_directories` allows you to set the correct paths in all 3 cases.

see also `target_link_libraries` which can be used to ensure that libraries that your library depends on are pulled into any dependent target.

Confused yet? It took me months to get my head around this. Once I did, I realised how incredibly powerful CMAKE is.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information you provided, definitely deserves an upvote. The problem is partially solved. I mean, this specific problem is solved but I now face the problem mentioned in the comments below. I do not know if this is related to CMake but an educated guess tell me it is. If you have some idea about that feel free to weigh in about it. Thanks again for the additional informations.

Comment: order of library targets matters. tell your replacement library that it also depends on VTK components. It will then carry the dependencies through and make sure they are linked in the correct order.

Comment: Isn't that already what I'm doing with target_link_libraries(TrackballCamera InteractorStyleTrackballCamera ${VTK_LIBRARIES})

Comment: ah yes. Oddly the error seems to be that your new library has not been linked into your executable? It's difficult to tell without seeing the whole CMAKE project (and no, I don't have time to sit and debug it for you :) )

Comment: Because that was what was suggested by @Angew in the comments before but it seems that this is not enough. By the new library not linked with the executable, isn't the target_link_libraries meant to do just that?

Comment: you have to call target_link_libraries(myExecutable myLibs ... otherLibs) against your executable target also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93485/discussion-between-lbesancon-and-richard-hodges).

Comment: I think that's what i do already with this line target_link_libraries(TrackballCamera vtkHybrid vtkWidgets InteractorStyleTrackballCamera)